# Only first Generator Expression in CMake target_sources() evaluated

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to add sources to a CMake target depending on the compile definitions of that target. To do so I'm using the following generator expression:

```
target_sources( tgt PRIVATE
    "$<$<IN_LIST:MY_DEF,$<TARGET_PROPERTY:COMPILE_DEFINITIONS>>:src1.cpp>"
    "$<$<IN_LIST:MY_DEF,$<TARGET_PROPERTY:COMPILE_DEFINITIONS>>:src2.cpp>"
)
```

This adds `src1.cpp` to the target as expected, but not `src2.cpp`. The generator expressions are exactly the same. If I change the order of the lines `src2.cpp` is added, but not `src1.cpp`. If I replace the second generator expression by `"$<1:src2.cpp>"` both files are added properly.

I tried with and without quotes, I tried putting the lines in two separate `target_sources()` calls, but nothing changed. I added more sources without generator expressions before, in between and after the generator lines and those where added properly.

I checked the resulting source lists after configuration and after generation with

```
get_target_property( DBGSOURCES tgt SOURCES )
message( STATUS "${DBGSOURCES}" )
add_custom_target( genexdebug COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "'$<TARGET_PROPERTY:tgt,SOURCES>'" )
```

and the result after configuration is the expected `;` separated list

```
$<$<IN_LIST:MY_DEF,$<TARGET_PROPERTY:COMPILE_DEFINITIONS>>:src1.cpp>;$<$<IN_LIST:MY_DEF,$<TARGET_PROPERTY:COMPILE_DEFINITIONS>>:src2.cpp>
```

but the result after generation has only the first source file:

```
src1.cpp;
```

What is going on here and how can I get both source files added to my target?

Comment: Hmm, strange. I'm not able to reproduce this. You might try the full generator expression signature for the target property `$<TARGET_PROPERTY:tgt,COMPILE_DEFINITIONS>` instead, but what you have should work. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the idea and affirmation, unfortunately it didn't change anything. I'm on Arch Linux, CMake 3.17.3, cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.13) (also tried 3.17), tried clang 10.0 and gcc 10.1